# Select only a cell in UltraWinGrid

Tags: c#, select, cell, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I want only the cell to be selected when I click on any cell in my ultragrid; Not the ENTIRE ROW!! Currently, the whole row is highlighted (as selected) when I click on a cell. How do I change the selection (highlighting) to the clicked cell only.

I've tried:

```
e.Layout.Override.CellClickAction = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.CellClickAction.CellSelect;
e.Layout.Override.SelectTypeCell = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.SelectType.Extended;
e.Layout.Override.SelectTypeCol = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.SelectType.None;
e.Layout.Override.SelectTypeRow = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.SelectType.None;
```

But nothing works! Help!

Comment: Could you look at [this discussion](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/59648/303163.aspx) on the infragistics forum and check if it's your case?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the comment Steve. But the problem was something else. We have a set of default themes set at runtime, which was creating the problem. So I had to override them and set my themes explicitly. That solved it! Anyways, Thanks.